# Insert text documents in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I am very new to Apache Solr. I understand that Solr accepts a CSV, JSON or XML format and not a TXT documents. Is it necessary to convert a text document into JSON or XML before sending the document to Solr?

Can you please guide me how to insert the text documents in Apache Solr?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DIH functionality of solr. DIH is Data Import Handler. Here you can use File
Import the files using the FileDataSource.

You can refer the below page for your further reference
[DIH](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)

Comment: I am trying Apache Solr with Python. @Abhijit Bashetti

Comment: You have to do the configuration on the solr side...You can invoke the solr through REST API

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: DIH is used for structured data. But I have text of CVs(Curriculum Vitae). How Apache Solr will understand field and data. Because there is no separator. For e.g. Name  Ketan Patel   Role    Software Developer @Abhijit Bashetti

Comment: All the data extracted from the file will be stored in a field called text. Mention the same field in schema file with required tokenization and filters.